# Why is the gravitational potential energy of ideal uniform massive spring $mgx/2$, not $mgx$?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, spring

In [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_%28spring%E2%80%93mass_system%29) Wikipedia page,

$$L= T-V = \frac{1}{2}\frac{m}{3}\dot{x}^2 + \frac{1}{2}M \dot{x}^2 - \frac{1}{2} k x^2 - \frac{m g x}{2} - M g x$$

where $mgx/2$ refers to gravitational potential energy of ideal spring. But I do not get why it's $mgx/2$ instead of $mgx$. What is the reason?

Comment: maybe trying to derive the results yourself from scratch would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x$ is the extension of the spring. If you extend the spring by a distance $x$, keeping the other end fixed, its centre-of-mass moves by $\frac{x}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

If the spring is stretching by an amount of $x$, its centre of mass is displaced by an amount of $x/2$.